# Coming up with a regex solution

Tags: regex

I have a page that has content on it that I need to try extract a number from with a regex.

Here is an example of the format of the page

```
Text here
<script type="text/javascript">
    var USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = "12345";
    var USER_FULL_NAME = "";
    var IS_INTERNATIONAL_USER = false;
</script>
Text here
```

From this content I need to get the value of user_account_number which would be 12345.

I tried something like this USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER([\s\S])=([\s\S])""; which finds the part i need but not sure how to only get whats in those quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the number of spaces around `=` isn't fixed. Hence, you can use this regex:

```
USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER\s*=\s*"(.*)"
```

[Online test](http://regex101.com/r/pG1wC0)

Answer (score 0):

```
/USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = "(.*)";/
```

Returns: `12345`

http://regex101.com/r/dW2hK7

Answer (score 0):

i would try something like:

```
USER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = "[1-9]*"
```